# Get count of characters of textbox by angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I just started to learn angularjs so may be this question looks silly.

I have this input tag :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="H1" name="H1" placeholder="Enter Something..." ng-trim="false" ng-model="seo.H1" required ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="50">
```

I am  gonna show the count of characters of input tag in the span tag :

```
<span class="pull-right" style="color: gray">{{ seo.H1.length }}/50</span>
```

But the problem is , it starts to count from 5th character and when input gets 50 characters , span shows nothing .

how can i fix the problem ?

Comment: Iit's not a problem, it's how `ng-minlength` and `ng-maxlength` works. You don't have a value in model variable when the string is out of these bounds. If you always need the content just remove these attributes and manually handle too many/few chars cases

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not the span itself. Everything works as expected.

Here is how it goes:

You have added ng-minlength which sets minimum lenght for the input to be valid.

You have added ng-maxlenght which sets maximum length for the input to be valid, and be able for the user to enter.

```
seo.H1.length
```

will take values from 5 to 50

Answer (score 1):

ng-minlength and ng-maxlength attributes problem in here, remove the attributes ,until satisfy your ng-minlength and ng-maxlength condition it holds text box `undefined` so that reason length is '0' whenever characters less than 5 and maximum up to 50.